# Bash: Find and replace all variable characters up to a constant character with a constant string

Tags: bash, replace

I've seen many search and replace threads based on the assumption that 1. you either know what string or substring you are explicitly looking for or 2. you know the exact position it is at within the string or 3. both combined. 
In my situation I have one csv file containing one column and 1M rows. e.g.

```
1,google.com
2,yahoo.com
3,twitter.com
4,xyz.com
```

For every column, I want to replace every character (the incrementing integers) **up to and including** the comma with the http semicolon dble forward slash dubdubdub

So far I have the following

```
HTTPSTRING="http://www."
cat X.csv << Will this ensure that the while block is executed on this file?
while IFS=, read line
  do {$line/(.*?),/HTTPSTRING} << This is where I am having trouble
done
exit 0
```

and I would likea text file containing one URL per line e.g.

```
http://www.google.com
...
http://www.${999,999_more_urls}
```

Thank you so much in advance

Lewis

Answer (score 1):

This does a greedy match, which would be problematic if you ever have any commas other than the one that separates the initial integer from the characters you want to retain. But it works on your sample X.csv file, producing a Y.csv file that meets your output specification.

```
HTTPSTRING="http://www."
while read line
do
  echo ${line/*,/$HTTPSTRING}
done < X.csv > Y.csv
exit 0
```

For what it's worth, if you put this in a script, you can take the file input/input redirection parts out of the code itself, and instead apply them when calling the script.

If you're not strictly limited to bash itself, you might want to consider using sed. Either of these should do what you want, differing only in whether you prefer to escape the slashes in your string or use a non-standard delimiter:

```
sed 's/[0-9]*,/http:\/\/www./' X.csv > Y.csv
sed 's~[0-9]*,~http://www.~' X.csv > Y.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is close. You can pipe the output of `cat` directly to the `while` loop, but it's better to use input redirection ( `< X.csv`). Using `IFS=,` before `read` will split the line into fields separated by a comma, but you are just missing a variable to hold the second field.

```
HTTPSTRING="http://www."
while IFS=, read number domain
do 
    echo "$HTTPSTRING$domain"
done < X.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use commands only, there is no need for an explicit Bash loop :

```
cut -d',' -f2 < X.csv | sed 's_^_http://www._' > Y.txt
```

Notice that the usual `/` used after the `s` in `sed` is replaced by `_` because it is included in the string to replace. `^` matches the start of the line.